# Execution order in GCC statement expressions

Tags: c++, gcc, gcc-statement-expression

I found that there is a different execution order between two similar statements(the only difference is the below one has an additional `;`). The destructor order is different. Does C++ have a corresponding specification about that or it's only an unspecified behavior?

Environment: GCC10

```
#include <iostream>

template <int num>
struct S {
  S() {std::cout << "S(" << num << ")\n"; }
  ~S() {std::cout << "~S(" << num << ")\n"; }
};

int main() {
  ({S<1>(), S<2>();});
  std::cout << "-----------------------------------\n";
  ({S<3>(), S<4>();;});
}
```

output:

```
S(1)
S(2)
~S(1)
~S(2)
-----------------------------------
S(3)
S(4)
~S(4)
~S(3)
```

Comment: This is not standard C++. This is a GCC extension known as [statement expression](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html)

Comment: If by C++ you mean the C++ standard, then it doesn't specify any particular desturctor order for this program, for the simple reason that this program is ill-formed.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik you are right. So I added a new program without statement expressions.

Comment: Temporaries created as part of the evaluation of a full expression are destroyed at the end of that full expression, in the reverse order of construction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not standard C++. This is a GCC extension known as [statement expression](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html). A compound statement enclosed in parentheses can appear where an expression is allowed. If the last statement in the brace-enclosed block is an expression statement, then the value of this expression is also the value of the overall statement expression; otherwise, the statement expression is of type `void` and has no value.

Your first example is roughly equivalent to

```
([](){ return S<1>(), S<2>(); })();
```

(that's a lambda that's created and then called immediately). There's a comma expression that creates `S<1>` and `S<2>` temporaries. `S<1>` is destroyed, `S<2>` is, technically, copied to the return value - but that copy is elided. If it weren't for this copy elision, you'd see

```
S<1>()
S<2>()
S<2>(S<2>&&)  // (1) move constructor
~S<2>()  // (2) the original temporary is destroyed
~S<1>()
~S<2>()  // the copy is destroyed outside of the lambda
```

But the pair (1)/(2) is elided, leaving the sequence you observe in your example.

In the second example, the last statement within the braces is not an expression, so the whole thing doesn't have a value either. It's roughly equivalent to

```
([](){ S<3>(), S<4>(); return; })();
```

Both temporaries are created and destroyed within the lambda, and the usual rules apply - temporaries are destroyed in the reverse order of construction.